# How to display different ccs-style depending on php condition

Tags: php, css

Basically, I have an upvote or downvote button for users. When users click the upvote or downvote, the corresponding button changes depending on the user input.

My problem is how do I display which post did the user upvoted or downvoted when a user refreshes the page?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(user_upvoted){
?>
    <style>
    .button<?php echo $button_id;?>
    {//css for upvote}
    </style>
<?php
}
else if(user_downvote){
?>
    <style>
    .button<?php echo $button_id;?>{//ccs for downvote}
    </style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is my buttons' code:

```
while($row=$query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
$nid = $row['nid'];
{
    <button class="button<?php echo $nid;?>" id="<?php echo $nid ; ?>" name="up">
}
```

This works but this code seems so dirty and don't feel right if you get my meaning.
PS: This is also in a php while loop that's why this is the method I tried.
What's a cleaner method of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code as below:

```
<?php
while($row=$query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $nid = $row['nid'];
    // Write your logic here for $user_upvoted and $user_downvote variable

    $btnExtraClass = '';
    if($user_upvoted){
    $btnExtraClass = 'button_upvote';
    } 
    if($user_downvote){
    $btnExtraClass = 'button_downvote';
    }
?>
<button class="button<?php echo $nid;?> <?php echo $btnExtraClass;?>" id="<?php echo $nid ; ?>" name="up">
<?php
}
?>
```

and then write your CSS rules separately.

```
<style>
.button_upvote {......}
.button_downvote {......}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question seems bit confusing. Can you first help me explain below points

1) Are you storing your upvote/downvote selected by user in the database ?
Also why are you suing class here

```
if(user_upvoted){
?>
<style>
.button<?php echo $button_id;?>
{//css for upvote}
</style>
```

It should be an id. if you are uniquely identifying them, then go for a id